# Parsing and formatting LocalDate with unnecessary time and timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

**Edit :**

I opened a bug and it has been confirmed by Oracle. You can follow the resolution here : https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8216414

---

I'm interfacing with a LDAP repository which store the birthdate of a person with the time and timezone like this :

- If the birthdate is "27-12-2018", then the LDAP string is "20181227000000+0000".

I cannot find a way to parse AND format the birthdate **using the same pattern**.

The following code works well for formatting but not for parsing :

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 27);
String pattern = "yyyyMMdd'000000+0000'";
DateTimeFormatter birthdateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

// Outputs correctly 20181227000000+0000
date.format(birthdateFormat);

// Throw a DatetimeParseException at index 0
date = LocalDate.parse("20181227000000+0000", birthdateFormat);
```

And the following code works well for parsing but not for formatting

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 27);
String pattern = "yyyyMMddkkmmssxx";
DateTimeFormatter birthdateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

// Throws a UnsupportedTemporalTypeException for ClockHourOfDay not supported
// Anyway I would have an unwanted string with non zero hour, minute, second, timezone
date.format(birthdateFormat);

// Parse correctly the date to 27-12-2018
date = LocalDate.parse("20181227000000+0000", birthdateFormat);
```

Which pattern could satisfy both parsing and formating ?

Am I forced to use 2 different patterns ?

I am asking because the pattern is configured in a property file. I want to configure 1 pattern only in this property file. I would like to externalize the pattern because the LDAP is not part of my project, it is a shared resource and I have no guarantee that the format cannot change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.DECEMBER, 27);
    String pattern = "yyyyMMddHHmmssxx";
    DateTimeFormatter birthdateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

    // Outputs 20181227000000+0000
    String formatted = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(birthdateFormat);
    System.out.println(formatted);

    // Parses to 2018-12-27T00:00Z
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("20181227000000+0000", birthdateFormat);
    System.out.println(odt);
    // Validate
    if (! odt.toLocalTime().equals(LocalTime.MIN)) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected time of day: " + odt);
    }
    if (! odt.getOffset().equals(ZoneOffset.UTC)) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected time zone offset: " + odt);
    }
    // Converts to 2018-12-27
    date = odt.toLocalDate();
    System.out.println(date);
```

The LDAP string represents both date, time and UTC offset. The good solution is to respect that and generate all of those when formatting (setting time of day to 00:00 and offset to 0) and parsing all of them back (at best also validating them to catch if any surprises should arise). Conversion between `LocalDate` and `OffsetDateTime` is straightforward when you know how.

**Edit 3: Allowing the pattern to be configured**

> … the pattern is configured in a property file… I want to configure 1
>   pattern only in this property file.
>
> … I have no guarantee that the format cannot change.

To take the possibility into account that the pattern may some day not contain time of day and/or no UTC offset use this formatter in the above code:

```
    DateTimeFormatter birthdateFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern(pattern)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .toFormatter()
            .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

This defines a default time of day (midnight) and a default offset (0). As long as time and offset are defined in the string from LDAP, the defaults are not used.

If you think it is getting too complicated, using two configured formats, one for formatting and one for parsing, may be the best solution (the least annoying solution) for you.

**Edit: Avoiding type conversions**

I consider the above the nice solution. However, if you insist an avoiding the conversion from `LocalDate` to `ZonedDateTime` using `atStartOfDay` and from `OffsetDateTime` using `toLocalDate`, that is possible through the following hack:

```
    DateTimeFormatter birthdateFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4, 4, SignStyle.NEVER)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
            .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
            .appendLiteral("000000+0000")
            .toFormatter();

    // Outputs 20181227000000+0000
    String formatted = date.format(birthdateFormat);
    System.out.println(formatted);

    // Parses into 2018-12-27
    date = LocalDate.parse("20181227000000+0000", birthdateFormat);
    System.out.println(date);
```

I am specifying the exact width of each field so that the formatter can know where to separate them in the string when parsing.

**Edit 2: Is this a bug in parsing?**

I would immediately have expected `yyyyMMdd'000000+0000'` to work for both formatting and parsing. You may try filing a bug with Oracle and seeing what they say, though I wouldn’t bee too optimistic.

Comment: Interesting approach but the drawback is that I cannot extract the pattern in a property file. The parser cannot determine by itself that yyyy means 4 characters, MM 2 and so on ?

Comment: Just saw your second edition, I ran into the same issue having a `DatetimeParseException` with `yyyyMMdd'000000+0000'`:(

Comment: It usually can determine that using the widths of the following fields. 20181227 as pattern `uuuuMMdd` poses no problem. It’s because the following zeroes are not defined as fields that it is getting confused. @Darnoj

Comment: @Darnoj I thought a little more about the need for the pattern to be configurable and added one more edit (edit 3).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I mark this as resolved even if the behaviour seen in your second edit seems like a bug to me... anyway I'll go for 2 patterns to keep it simpler.

Comment: Just to let you know : I transmitted the bug to Oracle https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8216414

Answer (score 2):

Since your LDAP string has zoned format `...+0000`, I would suggest using `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`.

This pattern `yyyyMMddHHmmssZZZ` would do the trick for both parsing and formatting.

```
LocalDate date =  LocalDate.of(2018, 12, 27);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssZZZ");
```

**Formatting**

- First convert your `LocalDate` to `ZonedDateTime`/`OffsetDateTime`:

  ```
  ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
  // or
  OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = date.atStartOfDay().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
  ```
- Then format it:

  ```
  // Both output correctly 20181227000000+0000
  System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(formatter));
  // or 
  System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(formatter));
  ```

**Parsing**

- First parse the `ZonedDateTime`/`OffsetDateTime`:

  ```
  // Both parse correctly
  ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("20181227000000+0000", formatter);
  // or
  OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("20181227000000+0000", formatter);
  ```
- Once you have `ZonedDateTime`/`OffsetDateTime`, you can simply retrieve the `LocalDate` like this:

  ```
  LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(zonedDateTime);
  // or
  LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(offsetDateTime);
  ```

---

**Update**

Both *parsing* and *formatting* can be simplified to one-liners:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(formatter.parse(ldapString));

String ldapString = OffsetDateTime.of(date, LocalTime.MIN, ZoneOffset.UTC).format(formatter);
```

In case you're still unsatisfied with the code above then you can extract the logic to utility methods:

```
public LocalDate parseLocalDate(String ldapString) {
    return LocalDate.from(formatter.parse(ldapString));
}

public String formatLocalDate(LocalDate date) {
    return OffsetDateTime.of(date, LocalTime.MIN, ZoneOffset.UTC)
                         .format(formatter);
}
```

Comment: `+0000` is an offset, not a time zone, so `OffsetDateTime` matches better. Otherwise the exactly right solution.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks. It Makes sense. I will add `OffsetDateTime` to my answer.

Comment: So there is no way to handle this only through the pattern but I have to juggle with startOfDay ? This is really weird... How comes if I had to extract the date from a string looking like "year = 2018, month = 12 and day = 27" ? I would have to use a `java.util.regex.Matcher` and `java.util.regex.Pattern` to do the job?

Comment: Well, actually it works with the example in my previous comment. The pattern `'year = 'yyyy', month = 'MM', and day = 'dd` can format and parse correctly. It seems like a very specific bug in the DateTimeFormatter...

Answer (score 1):

Stupid simple solution:

```
    String s1 = "20181227000000+0000";
    DateTimeFormatter yyyyMMdd = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(s1.substring(0, 8), yyyyMMdd);
    System.out.println("date = " + date);
    String s2 = date.format(yyyyMMdd) + "000000+0000";
    System.out.println("s2 = " + s2);
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

Comment: That breaks the wanted behaviour : "using the same pattern". Actually I wonder why I would be forced to use 2 different patterns in order to deal with the same date format...

Comment: I only see a single pattern used here, and it does parse and produce the string you want. So not sure what the actual problem is. You can probably only use a pattern if you use a ZonedDateTime instead of a LocalDate.

Comment: Well, saying that the pattern is configured in a property file, you would have 2 different keys : a parsePattern with "yyyyMMdd" and a trailingCharacterForDate with "000000+0000". I want to configure 1 pattern only in this property file.

Comment: Why externalize such things in a properties file since your date fomat is constant? As I said, you could do what you want with a ZonedDateTime, but then you'd have to hardcode that you want the LocalDate to be transformed to a ZonedDateTime using the start of the day and the UTC offset. If you also want to externalize than, you're back to square one.

Comment: I would like to externalize the pattern because the LDAP is not part of my project, it is a shared resource and I have no guarantee that the format cannot change. I wouldn't do that with my own database for instance.