# Parse Timestamp in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, parsing, timestamp

I get a timestamp in the format "20210908094049.884Z". This is the last modify timestamp from an LDAP object. I use Spring Boot Ldap. I have no clue how to parse this String in a Datetime like dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Looks like the format is `YYYYmmddHHMMSS.sssZ`.

Comment: @AndyTurner more like `yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS`

Comment: What did your search bring up? Too much to list? ;-)

Comment: @AndyTurner I had the same thought, but the modifyTimestamp in LDAP is "08.09.2021 11:40:49" according to "20210908094049.884Z" - 094049 does not match 11:40:49...

Comment: @SenNoRikyu are you in a UTC+2 timezone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing and formatting LocalDate with unnecessary time and timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943372/parsing-and-formatting-localdate-with-unnecessary-time-and-timezone). I know the question is not identical, but it’s about parsing an LDAP timestamp, so maybe you can get what you need from the answers there and modify them to your need.

Comment: @AndyTurner maybe yes, thank you for your help.

Comment: @AndyTurner no not on that system

Comment: @OleV.V. thx for your answere, that helps. I still know about the outdatet SimpleDatetime :)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and/or `Instant` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```java
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating new simple date formatter with the format you've given
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");

        // Defining the input date
        String inputDate = "20210908094049.884Z";

        // Parsing the date, catching the parse exception if date is malformatted
        Date date = null;
        try {
            // Date ends on a Z, we remove this Z (Z is for timezone UTC +0:00)
            date = format.parse(inputDate.replace("Z", ""));
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Giving following output:

```
Wed Sep 08 09:40:49 CEST 2021
```

**Edit:**
Here another even better solution from Ole V.V.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = DateTimeFormatter
                // Defining pattern to parse
                .ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSXX")
                // Defining input to parse with pattern
                .parse("20210908094049.884Z", Instant::from);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

Output is an instant with value:

```
2021-09-08T09:40:49.884Z
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry then. Thats just the way I've learnt it.

Comment: That’s the way we all learned it prior to java.time coming out in 2014 and effectively replacing the old classes (removing the `Z` would have been wrong in Java 7 too, though).

Comment: Well this question seems dead anyway. If you have a soluting using java.time feel free to share it!

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSSXX").parse("20210908094049.884Z", Instant::from)`. Yields an `Instant` of `2021-09-08T09:40:49.884Z`.

Comment: Ty, I've added your solution to my answer

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your work with timestamps.

The LDAP timestamp format has a number of allowed variations (see the link at the bottom). The following formatter takes many of them into account, not all of them.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter LDAP_PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss")
        .optionalStart()
        .appendPattern("[.][,]")
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 9, false)
        .optionalEnd()
        .appendPattern("[XX][X]")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

With this formatter we may for example parse your string into an `OffsetDateTime`:

```
    String ldapTimestampString = "20210908094049.884Z";
    OffsetDateTime timestamp = OffsetDateTime.parse(ldapTimestampString, LDAP_PARSER);
    System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Output is:

> 2021-09-08T09:40:49.884Z

### Formatting

To convert the timestamp to a string containing date and time you need to decide on a time zone for that since it is never the same date nor the same time in all time zones.

Use this formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
```

Then do:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Pacific/Tarawa");
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = timestamp.atZoneSameInstant(zone);
    String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
```

> 08.09.2021 21:40

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [GeneralizedTime](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/GeneralizedTime) on ldapwiki defining the LDAP timestamp format.